# Disable a style in VCL application

Tags: delphi, vcl-styles

I am adding the a VCL style into my application but am also giving the users an option to turn this off but I cannot figure out how to do this globally at runtime.

Setting "TStyleManager.AutoDiscoverStyleResources := false" almost works but it pops up with an error message saying "Style {style set} not found" but after dismissing the message does exactly what I want.

This code I would expect to work but does not...

```
if (not ParamObj.UseDarkStyle) then
begin
  //TStyleManager.AutoDiscoverStyleResources := false;
  TStyleManager.SetStyle(TStyleManager.SystemStyle);
end;
```

I also tried (originally)

```
TStyleManager.TrySetStyle('Windows');
```

but this also does not work.

I have tried this both sides of "Application.Initialize;" with no difference

What am I missing?
Thanks in advance,
Martin

Comment: The `TStyleManager.SetStyle(TStyleManager.SystemStyle);` code is  correct, the only explanation I can think of is maybe you are not adding the  `Vcl.Styles` unit to your project.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. There was a TStyleManager.TrySetStyle further in the initialization code that I did not notice that was resetting it back to the dark style.